# How to get mian image url form the resized one in wordpress?

Tags: image, wordpress

I need a help. I need to get the main url of an image uploaded in wprdpress from the url of the re sized one's url. If possible the link of the attachment. Experts please help. Thanks in advanced.

Example-

re sized url-

```
1. http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1-90x120.jpg
2. http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2013/01/image-1-1040x320.png
3. http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/custom_upload_folder/image-1-430x210.jpg
```

what i'm looking for-

```
1. http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1.jpg or http://www.example.com/?attactment_id=12
2. http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2013/01/image-1.png or http://www.example.com/?attactment_id=12
3. http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/custom_upload_folder/image-1.jpg or ttp://www.example.com/?attactment_id=12
```

I can't use regex as i'm novice at this. again i can't use `substr` as image sizes of the resized ones are different.
attactment_id is the attachment id if the image is uploaded through the wordpress media uploader.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may not do it with substr, but some other string operations may help. This will work but I wouldn't recommend using it as it's not very efficient (too many var assignments) and should just give you an idea. However you may still use it if you're not going to parse these urls with some heavy production code.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1-90x120.jpg';
list($first, $second, $third, $forth) = explode("-", $url);
echo $first.'-'.$second.'-'.$third.'.jpg';
```

There are plenty of examples of how to work with strings, especially with explode and implode functions, in order to make it efficient and more elegant.
On the other hand, I don't believe that Wordpress can anyhow retrieve back the original url out from the ones you have provided.

Comment: Thank you so much for your afford. But its not obvious that every time i'll be able to explode based on the url because file name and directory could possibly don't have dash in them or some other similar things to explode with. Thanks again but i was looking for a wordpress solution rather than a php solution.

Answer (score 0):

> **Using this code get main upload image url:**

```
<?php
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full');   
?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<a href="#"> <img class="img_slide" src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> </a>
<?php 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your afford but its not what i want. maybe you didn't understood my problem. I was seeking for a way to get the main file url using the resized one. let the function is get_image_main() and i want something like $main_image_url = get_image_main($resized_image_url); Thanks again.